# Self-Signed certificate for LDAP on Sun Directory Server

Tags: ldap, certutil

I am wondering if some one could provide me with steps to self-signed certificate using certutil. I want the cert for Sun Directory Server 5.2 Patch 6.

Comment: Does [this very extensive Oracle blog entry](http://blogs.oracle.com/baban/entry/steps_to_setup_ssl_using) help you?

Answer (score 0):

certutil -S -s "CN=My Name" -n my-certificate-alias -x -t "C,C,C" -1 -2 -5 -f fileWithPassword -d directory